# Vegas slideshow installation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

Hi i have a problem with vegas slideshow installation:
http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/setup/

I downloaded vegas from http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/ (on github there are others files);

After i created an index.html (and put it on the vegas folder)

First of all thank you, I apologize for my ignorance, but could you explain more detail?
 All files are in folder's root: vegas.min.css, vegas.min.js, index.js, index.html, bridge.jpg

I also tried this way (Without results):

-index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vegas.min.css">
  <script src="vegas.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 100vh">
    <div id="ShowSlideShowHere" style="height: 100vh"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

-index.js:

```
$("#ShowSlideShowHere, body").vegas({
    slides: [
        { src: "bridge.jpg" },
        { src: "/img/slide2.jpg" },
        { src: "/img/slide3.jpg" },
        { src: "/img/slide4.jpg" }
    ]
});
```

**EDIT** I HAVE SOLVED 
I had omitted the string
*$(function(){*

-index.js:

```
$(function(){
$("#ShowSlideShowHere, body").vegas({
    slides: [
        { src: "bridge.jpg" },
        { src: "/img/slide2.jpg" },
        { src: "/img/slide3.jpg" },
        { src: "/img/slide4.jpg" }
    ]
});
});
```

Comment: What _is_ happening?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That includes intended behaviour and current behaviour. For example, what errors are you getting? Also be sure to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ElementToAttachSlideTo").vegas({
slides: [
    { src:'bridge.jpg', fade:1000 },
    { src:'/img/bg2.jpg', fade:1000 },
    { src:'/img/bg3.jpg', fade:1000 }
 ]
});
```

Hi, by the looks of it you have to create an element in your body section of html file and then attach the slider to that element using a jquery selector.